# Network Scanning with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have an Active Directory.I need to store information like:

- **Online Computers**
- **Online Computers Hostname**
- **Ip Address**
- **Mac Address**

to a list. Is there any Class for doing this in C#. And also is this possible doing this from ASP.NET?

Comment: What do you mean by "I wanna check Online Computers", can you explain a bit more.

Comment: For example there are 100 computer in my domain.But only 50 computer is open and working.I wanna get this 50 computer's mac address,ip address and Hostname info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at System.DirectoryServices and possibly check out the following websites:

http://www.willasrari.com/blog/query-active-directory-users-using-c/000133.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx